# setInterval keeps running even after clearInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Thanks in advance.
This is my question : It is Quiz website for couple.

Before partner finish quiz, It send get request to server every 5s.
but the problem is even partner's answers are set, setInterval never stops.

but if I refresh my website, It works well.
Can you please give me advise?

```
  const postAnswers = useGetResults();
  const postPartnerAnswers = useGetPartnerResults();
  const [myResult, setMyResult] = useState<FinalAnswer | undefined>();
  const [partnerResult, setPartnerResult] = useState<FinalAnswer | undefined>();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const init = async () => {
    try {
      const email = localStorage.getItem('email');
      const partnerEmail = localStorage.getItem('partnerEmail');
      if (email !== undefined && partnerEmail !== undefined) {
        // localStorage에 이메일 값들이 있으면,
        const result = await postAnswers(email, partnerEmail);
        const otherResult = await postPartnerAnswers(email, partnerEmail);

        if (result.answers !== undefined && otherResult.answers !== undefined) {
          // 몽고디비에서 받아온 값이 둘다 있으면
          setMyResult(result);
          setPartnerResult(otherResult);
        } else {
          // 몽고디비에서 받아온 값이 없으면
          console.log(result.answers, otherResult.answers);
          setIsLoading(true);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorMessage('로딩하는 도중 에러가 발생했습니다');
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myResult !== undefined && partnerResult !== undefined) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log('둘다 값이 있어요!');
      console.log(isLoading);
    }
  }, [myResult, partnerResult]);

  const timer = () => {
    return setInterval(() => {
      init();
      console.log('isLoading', isLoading);
      if (isLoading === false) {
        console.log('clear');
        clearInterval(timer());
      }
    }, 5000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading === true) {
      console.log('둘다 값이 없어요!');
      timer();
    }
    if (isLoading === false) {
      console.log('clear');
      clearInterval(timer());
    }
  }, [isLoading]);
```

deployed website : https://www.couple-quiz.com/

Comment: The problem is that everytime you run `timer()`, you are making a new setInterval call. You'll need to refactor your code to store the interval call somewhere (for example `setTimer(setInterval(...))`), and then clear that.

Comment: thank you  Ethansocal.
I solved this problem using duplicate setTimeout. anyone undergo same problem can refer here ==> https://ko.javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@Ethansocal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15446995/ethansocal) comment:

Your code is calling `clearInterval(timer())` which will create a new interval that it will immediately clear. It seems that you are confusing the API of `removeEventListener` and `clearInterval`.

`clearInterval` should be called with the identifier returned by `setInterval`.

I suggest getting rid of the `timer` function and rewriting your last `useEffect` to make it return [a cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) when `isLoading` is `true`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isLoading) {
    console.log('둘다 값이 없어요!');
    const interval = setInterval(init, 5_000);
    return () => { clearInterval(interval) };
  } else {
    console.log('clear');
  }
}, [isLoading]);
```